# How to parse Redis AOF file?

Tags: database, redis, node-redis

I am trying to understand how Redis AOF file works and maybe write a parser given some simple Redis AOF file. Right now I generated an AOF file by doing these commands in Redis:

```
SET firstkey firstvalue
SET secondkey secondvalue
```

and the generated AOF file looks like this:

```
*2
$6
SELECT
$1
0
*3
$3
SET
$8
firstkey
$10
firstvalue
*3
$3
SET
$9
secondkey
$11
secondvalue
```

I can see the keywords like firstkey, firstvalue and SET, etc. But I didn't quite understand the rest, espcially what all these numbers like `*2`, `$6` means, and how they work when redis trying to read the aof file and rebuild the database. I couldn't find any file format document online either, so any help is appreciated!

Comment: Interesting question. Had a look at the source already? https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/aof.c

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`*N` is the number of arguments of the command, and `$M` is the length, i.e. the number of bytes, of each argument.

In your case, Redis executed 3 commands: `SELECT 0`, `SET firstkey firstvalue` and `SET secondkey secondvalue`.

`SELECT 0` command has `2` arguments, i.e. *SELECT* and *0*. The length of the first argument is `6`, and the length of the second argument is `1`. So AOF file records:

`*2\r\n$6\r\nSELECT\r\n$1\r\n0\r\n`

You can try the other 2 commands for practice.

Comment: For more information, take a look at the Redis serialization protocol (RESP) specification https://redis.io/docs/reference/protocol-spec/